# Parsing test_and_set

Tags: synchronization, locking

I am having trouble understanding test_and_set, so I wanted to make sure that I parsed the algorithm correctly.

```
do { while (test_and_set(&lock))
; /* do nothing */
/* critical section */
lock = false;
/* remainder section */
} while (true);



boolean test_and_set (boolean *target)
{
boolean rv = *target;
*target = TRUE;
return rv:
}
```

1st: lock is initialize to false, test_and_set returns false but changes lock to true; therefore, do nothing
2nd: lock is set to true, test_and_set returns true and changes lock to true; therefore, critical section is ran, lock is set to false.

rinse and repeat

Answer (score 0):

> 1st: lock is initialize to false, test_and_set returns false but changes lock to true; therefore, do nothing

no, `test_and_set` returns false, so exit while loop and execute critical section

lock is set to true to prevent other processes getting false from `test_and_set` while critical section is executing.